# async before in scalatest for scalajs

Tags: scala, scalatest, scala.js

In the code example below, how can I wait for `ajaxCall()` to finish before starting `test 1` when using `scalatest` to test Scala.js code ? I cannot use `await` in Scala.js.

```
class ClientGetEntityDynTest
    extends AsyncFunSuite
    with Matchers
    with BeforeAndAfter {

  implicit override def executionContext =
    scala.scalajs.concurrent.JSExecutionContext.Implicits.queue

  before {
    ajaxCall(...) // returns Future[...]
    ... // I would like to wait for ajaxCall to finish before starting test 1
  }

  test("test 1") {
    ...
    getEntityDyn(...) // returns Future[Assertion]
  }
}
```

[This](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/issues/953) one year old issue seems to be related but not really resolved.

One simple possibility would be to make my own `testWithBefore` method... that calls `test` and waits for a `Future` to complete before calling `test` but maybe it is possible to do this without this workaround.

Comment: I assume that this ajax call is necessary to complete before any of your tests can start. If this is true then why not just block waiting for the future to complete inside the `before{}` with some reasonable timeout? Like `Await.result(ajaxCall, 10 seconds)`?

Comment: This is Scala.js.  There's no such thing as Await -- it's literally impossible, because the JavaScript engine doesn't work like that.

Comment: @AlexanderArendar Yes, this is why I am asking this question. For now I just write my own `test` method...

Comment: Sorry, jhegedus, but I don't yet understand. You say that the `ajaxCall` returns `Future[...]`. If this is an instance of `scala.concurrent.Future` type that you should be able to use `Await.result(...)` with it.
Or with Scala.js you have some limitations on which methods you can use? I have never used scala.js so probably my comment is naive in this regard :)

Comment: @AlexanderArendar yes, this explains it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: I thought that using scala.js you may write a code in Scala and it will then translate to JS. But i did not know that there are limitations on which Scala features/classes/constructs you may use.

Comment: It's not a scalajs limitation. It's a js limitation.

Comment: @AlexanderArendar Yeah -- you have to keep in mind that this is running in a JavaScript engine in a browser, and some stuff is literally impossible in that environment. The Scala *language* is all the same in Scala.js, but the *libraries* are not entirely identical.  And Future is a library feature, not a language one: it runs similarly but not quite identically in Scala.js, the major difference being that Await is impossible...

Comment: Thanks a lot, @JustinduCoeur, I've got it now. Video mentioned by jhegedus was also very great explanation.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you need to restructure your tests, to not use BeforeAndAfter. I'm not sure of the best solution, but the fall-back would be to create your own higher-order function, called something like `beforeAsync(fun: => Future[Any])`, and manually use that in your tests.

I *suspect* it wouldn't be too hard to take [BeforeAndAfter.scala](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/release-3.0.0/scalatest/src/main/scala/org/scalatest/BeforeAndAfter.scala), and create a variant `BeforeAndAfterAsyc` that has this `beforeAsync()` function in it, but I haven't tried doing so.